# I can't add OR operator inside my sql query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, medoo

My code look like this:

```
$database->update($campaign_table, $data_nga_posti , array("AND" => ["codice_pod" => $data_nga_posti['codice_pod'],("codice_pdr" =>NULL) ]));
```

So this is when my query execute:

```
UPDATE `field` SET `columnname` = 'data',`anothercm` = 'data',WHERE `codice_pod` = 'IT001E35563561' AND `codice_pdr` IS NULL
```

I want to my query look like this.

```
UPDATE `field` SET `columnname` = 'data',`anothercm` = 'data',WHERE `codice_pod` = 'IT001E35563561' AND (`codice_pdr` IS NULL OR `codice_pdr` ="")
```

but I dont know how to put OR(operator ) inside this code.

Comment: Are you using some kind of framework or ORM?

Comment: Could you possibly just use mysqli and a connection and then build the query yourself instead of using the update function?

Comment: NO sir,im not using any framework here.

Comment: @axhem Could you also post your `update()` method then?

Comment: we have not complete information about update method of $database object please show us your method and how it works

Comment: Guys im using a class called (class medoo)/http://medoo.in/api/where  to get data from a Form data.

Comment: `,WHERE` is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have never used this before, and have nothing to test with but the closted example posted in [the documentation](http://medoo.in/api/where) is:

```
$database->has("account", [
    "AND" => [
        "OR" => [
            "user_name" => "foo",
            "email" => "foo@bar.com"
        ],
        "password" => "12345"
    ]
]);
```

So I think this would work for you:

```
$database->update($campaign_table, $data_nga_posti, [
    "AND" => [
        OR => [
            "codice_pdr" =>NULL, 
            "codice_pdr" => ""
        ],
        "codice_pod" => $data_nga_posti['codice_pod']
    ]
]);
```

Comment: Yeah,this works for me,sure with some changes.So Thank you very much for your answers,its my first question and maybe im not very clear with my question,anyway the first is the first...  Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
array("AND" => ["codice_pod" => $data_nga_posti['codice_pod'],"OR" => ["codice_pdr" =>NULL,`codice_pdr` ="" ] ])
```

Comment: How can you possibly now this will work? He hasn't even posted his `update()` method yet.